# Integration of Email to Issue (GitLab)

Tags: email, git, support-tracker

I'm working with Gitlab CE to maintain my clients websites (and to collaborate with other developers). I'd like to have my clients sending Email to a specific address (lets say support@example.com) and automatically create an issue in Gitlab. It doesn't have to be the specific project as there could be a project "inbox" where the incoming issues could be sorted manually to the specific project.

I don't want the clients to be Gitlab users (but would be ok with a guest role / status). On the other hand it would be great if the client that has created an issue would receive comments on that.

Is there anything out there that will meet these requirements? I'm not bound to gitlab and will change if required.

Thanks in advance!